# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Auto Scaling configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have 2 machines running under an Elastic Beanstalk environment.
One of them is down since the last deployment.
I was hoping that the auto scaling configuration will initiate a new machine due to having a single machine available.

That didn't happen and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my auto scaling configuration:[image]

Comment: Is that machine showing Out Of service status in the ELB?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the exact term, but I'm sure that ELB showed me that only one instance was available. And the application status was degraded.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your rules contradict each other. It says if the number of unhealthy hosts are above 0, add a single host. If they are below 2, remove a single host. That may explain why you aren't seeing anything happening with your trigger.

Scaling triggers are used to bring in, or reduce, EC2 instances in your Auto Scaling group. This would be useful to bring in an additional instance(s) to maintain the same amount of computational power for your application while you investigate what caused the bad instance to fail. But this will not replace the instance.

To setup your instances to terminate after a certain period of being unhealthy you can follow the [documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html).

By default ELB pings port 80 with TCP, this is what determines the "health" of the EC2 instance, along with the on host EC2 instance status check. You can specify a **Application health check URL** to setup a customized health check that your application returns. Check out the more detailed customization of [Beanstalk ELBs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html).